# I cannot figure how to to dynamically add values to an array

Tags: php, arrays

How can I rewrite this please as I tried a few things and I just dont know the correct way to do it.  Instead of:

```
$files_to_zip = array(
    1,
    4,
    8
);
```

How can that be rewritten so that:

```
$explode_mods  = "1,4,8";
$mod_nums = explode(",", $explode_mods);

$files_to_zip = $mod_nums;
```

Basically $files_to_zip still needs to be in array format but I don't know how to only display each value into an array for the $files_to_zip variable.  This is part of a larger script and I am almost done so please do not show me a totally different code I just need $files_to_zip to be read as an array still. The $explode_mods will actually be a $_POST value in the real script where I enter numbers separated by commas and they will be inserted into the $files_to_zip array. Thank you.

Comment: What do you really mean?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. `$files_to_zip` (and `$mod_nums`) will be an array, containing the the elements `1`, `4,` and `8`.

Comment: I took the hint from the title, with "add values".. Let's see if I'm correct :)

Answer (score 1):

I think I read your question correctly: you already have other entries in `$files_to_zip` which you want to merge with `$explode_mods`?

Try this:

```
$files_to_zip = array('some', 'entries', 'here', 'already');
$explode_mods = "1,4,8";
$files_to_zip = array_merge($files_to_zip, explode(',', $explode_mods));
var_dump($files_to_zip);
```

Comment: Hello, I edited my original topic.  I think you may have me going in the right direction, still a little more tweaking.  I basically want $files_to_zip to be an array that I can insert values into from a form.  I just tried:    $explode_mods  = trim($_POST['mods']);

 $files_to_zip = array_merge(explode(",", $explode_mods));  and it almost worked

Comment: You will have to explain "an array that I can insert values into from a form" a bit more, I think.